# Javascript Recursive function to build tree from unsorted set

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

lets say im building a structure where

unsorted set

```
obj1 {id: random key, childsets : [blankcontainer], superkey: null}

obj2 {id: random key, childsets : [blankcontainer], superkey: obj1ID }

obj3 {id: random key, childsets : [blankcontainer], superkey: obj2ID }
```

to something like

```
obj1{contents, [obj2{contents, [obj3{contents, []}]}]
```

my line of thinking is with recursions, but I'm not sure how I'm going to traverse a check function for every end nodes, and when to end the recursion

Comment: Please provide an more illustrative example with expected input and output. Also please provide what you have tried so far.

Comment: ow sorry! edited it now thanks

Comment: Build a map from object key to object, instead of a set, and you won't even need recursion.

Comment: @chaosg0hd ... _"ow sorry! edited it now"_ ... formatting cosmetics to invalid pseudocode doesn't really help. The OP was ask to provide working example code (it can be little/small though and should not be the exact customer data by value, but by structure) for the input data and the expected result.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt and note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.